# How to add exception for errors(try, catch)

Tags: c#

This is my code for some console app. First thing that doesn't work very well is method SwitchLetters. When I input some string and press enter every letter goes to new line. I don't know why. Also i don't know how to display lower and upper  case in methods PrintBeforeSwitch and PrintAfterSwitch. And Exception how to use try and catch for some exception and which exception to use...

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
        Console.WriteLine("Please input string");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        NewString ns = new NewString();
        StringOperation so = new StringOperation();

        ns.SwitchLetters(input);
        so.PrintBeforeSwitch(input);
        so.PrintAfterSwitch(input);   
    }
}

class NewString
{
    private string newString;

    public string _NewString
    {
        get
        {
            return newString;
        }
        set
        {
            newString = value;
        }
    }
    public void SwitchLetters(string newStr)
    {
        StringBuilder myString = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < newStr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (char.IsUpper(newStr, i))
                myString.Append(char.ToLower(newStr[i]));
            else if (char.IsLower(newStr, i))
                myString.Append(char.ToUpper(newStr[i]));
            else
                myString.Append(newStr[i]);

            Console.WriteLine(myString.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(newStr.ToUpper());
        }

    }

}

class StringOperation
{
    private string inputString;
    //public NewString newSrt;

    public string InputString
    {
        get
        {
            return inputString;
        }
        set
        {
            inputString = value;
        }
    }

    public int VocalNumber(string str)
    {
        int num; 
        return num = str.Count(a => "aeiouAEIOU".Contains(a));
    }

    public int SpaceNumber(string str)
    {
        int num;
        return num = str.Count(b => b == ' ');
    }

    public List<int> LowerUpperCaseLattersNumber(string str)
    {
        int counterLower = 0;
        int counterUpper = 0;
        List<int> counter = new List<int>();
        foreach (char value in str)
        {
            if (char.IsLower(value))
            {
                counterLower++;
            }
            else
            {
                counterUpper++;
            }
        }

        counter.Add(counterLower);
        counter.Add(counterUpper);
        Console.WriteLine("Number of small latters is: {0}", counterLower);
        Console.WriteLine("Number of big letters is: {0}", counterUpper);
        return counter;
    }

    public string SwitchVocals(ref string str)
    {
        string vocals = str.Replace("a", "x").Replace("e", "x").Replace("i", "x").Replace("o", "x").Replace("u", "x").Replace("A", "X").Replace("E", "X").Replace("I", "X").Replace("O", "X").Replace("U", "X");
        Console.WriteLine(vocals);
        return vocals;
    }

    public void PrintBeforeSwitch(string str)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(str);
        Console.WriteLine("Information about string:");
        Console.WriteLine("Number of vowels: {0}", VocalNumber(str));
        Console.WriteLine("Number of space: {0}", SpaceNumber(str));
        Console.WriteLine("Number of small latters is: {0}", LowerUpperCaseLattersNumber(str));
        Console.WriteLine("Number of big letters is: {0}", LowerUpperCaseLattersNumber(str));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public void PrintAfterSwitch(string str)
    {
        SwitchVocals(ref str);
        Console.WriteLine("Information about string after switch:");
        Console.WriteLine("Number of vowels: {0}", VocalNumber(str));
        Console.WriteLine("Number of space: {0}", SpaceNumber(str));
        Console.WriteLine("Number of small latters is: {0}", LowerUpperCaseLattersNumber(str));
        Console.WriteLine("Number of big letters is: {0}", LowerUpperCaseLattersNumber(str));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
 }
```

Comment: I would suggest trying to ask less questions in one post, this can make it easier for users to answer and make it easier for you to ask a specific question with the current results and expected results

Comment: No problem :-) Try reading here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask this will help you to get better answers in the future. Welcome to StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea how to do the exception:

```
public void SwitchLetters(string newStr)
{
    try
    {

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();//this stops the program so you can read the error
    }

}
```

I think you had the two lines swapped around so.PrintBeforeSwitch and ns.SwitchLetters

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please input string");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    NewString ns = new NewString();
    StringOperation so = new StringOperation();

    so.PrintBeforeSwitch(input);
    ns.SwitchLetters(input);
    so.PrintAfterSwitch(input);   
}
```

If you use `Console.WriteLine("some string here");` it will do exactly as it says, write line. However you can use `Console.Write("some string here");` and it should add the text/string onto the existing line.

Can you please give us more information by what you mean "First thing that doesn't work very well is method SwitchLetters..." what should it do? What does it currently do?

To resolve your issue in the comment below remove the `Console.ReadLine()`

```
public void SwitchLetters(string newStr)
{
    StringBuilder myString = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < newStr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (char.IsUpper(newStr, i))
            myString.Append(char.ToLower(newStr[i]));
        else if (char.IsLower(newStr, i))
            myString.Append(char.ToUpper(newStr[i]));
        else
            myString.Append(newStr[i]);

        Console.WriteLine(myString.ToString());
        //Console.ReadLine(); This line needs to be removed
        Console.WriteLine(newStr.ToUpper());
    }

}
```

Comment: method SwitchLetters nedd to swap upper letter to small and reverse. When I input some string ex. MYstriGN they need to swap in mySTRIng, and the method works but i need to press enter every time I just want when i press once to swap in new line.